# Restricting clang warnings to my source files

Tags: c, clang, c89

I'm compiling a program using a library in C using clang. I want to check my program for errors (`-Wall -Weverything`) but I don't want to check the library. Is there a way to restrict clang's warnings to just my source files?

Comment: If the library is in the form of an object file, you don't need to do anything special. If you compile it, do it separately and just avoid adding those flags.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's not -- it's in source form. The library ( http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/ ) is in active development and I pull new sources several times a week.

Comment: How are you building it?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes. Or rather, using a custom build script which ultimately calls make (along with lots of other stuff) with appropriately customized options.

Comment: Well then. Can't you modify the script (and/or makefile) with a special target for that library? Build an object file out of it, and link to it. What's the issue? Are you getting those warnings when you include the headers?

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I'm getting hundreds of warnings from the library when I compile with `-Wall -Weverything`. FWIW my build script is basically this: http://pastebin.com/V8Z01uNs

Comment: `clang -Weverything` does warn about an awful lot of things that are not really relevant. When I use it, I suppress some of the warnings. I use `-Weverything -Wno-padded -Wno-vla -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-documentation-unknown-command` — take your pick on what you use.  For example, it is modestly ridiculous for `clang` to complain about people setting a feature-macro such as `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` when that's precisely what you're supposed to do to indicate that you want the code to be treated as POSIX 2008 source code. So, I ignore that warning. Pick and choose carefully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, good to know! That should be useful in helping dial back the number of warnings (there are a lot). Any idea on how to stop clang from warning about the included library?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I also get a *lot* of spurious shadowing warnings which I had to turn off with `-Wno-shadow`, I'm not sure if you see this much but that was the only one I had turned off up to this point.

Comment: Not at this time of night.  I'd have to go manual bashing.  IIRC, there is a way to suppress warnings from system headers in GCC; I forget what that is, too (and didn't find it on a medium fast scan of [Warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)).  But that would probably work with `clang` too.  As to `-Wshadow`, my code doesn't run into problems with that usually — though there are bound to be ways that I could run into problems with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a library header file is generating copious amounts warnings whenever you include it, you can try and solve by using a bit of indirection (what else).

So for a library header named `lib_a.h`, create a wrapper (`my_lib_a.h`) that looks something like this:

```
#ifdef __clang__
#  pragma clang diagnostic push
#  pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Weverything"
#endif

#include "lib_a.h"

#ifdef __clang__
#  pragma clang diagnostic pop
#endif
```

Now include it instead of directly including the library header.

Those [pragams](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas) will turn off the warnings for that particular library header only.

You can of course add support for other tool-chains, and even make this utility header the point of entry for all the problematic headers in your program. Precompiling it will make the overhead negligible.

Comment: It was really that easy? That did it! Thank you so much!